# Springboot 2.4 ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save an Image to a Oracle Database (Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0). Every time I use my repository to save it (update or insert statement) I get the following exception:

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes expected - got BLOB
```

My entity

```
@Entity
public class Profile {
@Id
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;

@Lob
@Column
private byte[] image;

//getters and setters

}
```

My Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Profile, Long> {
}
```

And last but not least my service method:

```
@Transactional
public void saveProfile(Profile profile) {
     profileRepository.save(profile);
}
```

my ddl script:

```
create table "profile"
(
    image BLOB not null,
    name varchar2(30) not null,
    ID NUMBER no null  primary key
);
```

I tried to change the image field type to `java.sql.Blob` but it didn't work either. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: How did you try to use `Blob` and what error did you get? You have to annotate it with `@Lob`. Can you also share the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `image` property with

```java
@Column
@Blob
private Blob image;
```

And when you'd want to display it, convert it:

```java
private byte[] toByteArray(Blob fromImageBlob) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      return toByteArrayImpl(fromImageBlob, baos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
  }



private byte[] toByteArrayImpl(Blob fromImageBlob, 
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos) throws SQLException, IOException {
    byte buf[] = new byte[4000];
    int dataSize;
    InputStream is = fromImageBlob.getBinaryStream(); 

    try {
      while((dataSize = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
        baos.write(buf, 0, dataSize);
      }    
    } finally {
      if(is != null) {
        is.close();
      }
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
  }
```

Comment: As mentioned I already I tried that didn't work.